# <a href=#> link redirecting to index. php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<div class="filter-portfolio pull-right">
  <ul>
    <li class="always-visible">
      **<a href="#">**Categories <span class="icon-caret-down"></span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".all">All</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".fashion">Fashion</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".nature">Nature</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".animals">Animals</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-filter=".arch">Architecture</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>`
```

Whenever I click on the `<a href="#">**Categories</a>` link it is redirecting me to the `index.php/#`. Can anyone help me find out why it's happening ?

Comment: but suppose like i'm on mysite.com/gallery.php but still when i click on the link it redirects to mysite.com/index.php/#

Comment: No it doesn't, and if it does, there's javascript and the History API controlling the URL's, or the hrefs aren't what you say there are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prevent default click handler:

```
$('.filter-portfolio a[href="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `#` sign scrolls the page to the top when the anchor is clicked, and adds the hash sign to the URL, if you don't want that, just prevent it

```
$('a[href="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also omit the href attribute like this and you would not need any javascript for it.

Like this:

```
<a data-filter=".all">All</a>
```